# Youngest age of political prodigy?

Tags: government

We all heard about child prodigies in music, sport, math, literature & science. But what could be the youngest age of a political child prodigy?

I want a child that could be able to rule on its own, not be just a figurehead where the real ruler is a regent.

The country is present day "democracy". But in practice it's a democracy in name only, the child's father was an autocrat who rigged elections and changed constitutions whenever he needed to, "There is no need for term limits my people love me". He ruled the country with an iron fist in a velvet glove, helped by his cronies in the business, military & police. The economy depends heavily on exporting mineral resources. When the mineral prices are high there's money for everyone, when they are low you have to pay the armed forces first. The child inherits his father's loyalties as long as it keeps paying them.

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about the environment, technology and time period in which this leader should arise?

Comment: Ruling is easy, you only need someone to obey you. Making good decisions as a ruler is considerably harder, and some people have been proven unable of that no matter their age. And of course, what "a good decision" is very opinion and context based (doing nothing when everything goes ok is a good decision, doing nothing when the country is sinking is a bad decision).

Comment: I think there are two key part to this: (1) the laws re age of legal adulthood and candidacy (assuming a democracy) and (2) the ability to gain followers, especially passionate/zealot followers.  The latter could be done (in theory) by someone of any age that was sufficiently skilled at rhetoric and applied psychology.  See also the fictional online political 'argument' between characters Locke and Demosthenes in _Ender's Game_.

Comment: @Catalyst, a lot of the child/adult interactions in Ender's Game depend on the adults not knowing that they're dealing with children and in particular cases the children not knowing they're dealing with people at all.

Comment: @Separatrix:  Just so!  And on today's internet, nobody knows you're a dog -- or a child, or an AI.  See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you're_a_dog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question and use of the term "prodigy" focus very heavily on the skills and abilities of the child in question. This is problematic because unlike a music, sport, or other type of prodigy, politics is a realm where MOST of the success or failure an individual is likely to achieve are not based on their own capabilities, but on the perception and reaction of OTHER PEOPLE. Hence, in politics, skill and "genius" is much less relevant than it would be in music or sports.

This is the same problem that was never really dealt with in the Ender's Game series. There was a simple assumption that a smart enough person would be able to rule the world because they were smart. That isn't actually how society works. Humans are hard-wired with certain attitudes toward authority and authority figures that can be considered part of "human nature". For example; we ALL seem to prefer (across all time periods and cultures) a taller individual as a leader. Studies of electorally based systems show a considerable bias toward people who are taller than average. Even going back to ancient times, one of the main points brought up by the ancient Israelites as a good reason to make Saul king over them was that he was tall! There are numerous historical examples of this bias as well. Obviously, this puts a child (or a woman) at a disadvantage. Another built in bias is reverence toward our elders. Once again, across virtually every culture and time period, human beings tend to defer to elders. From the perspective of simple survival, this makes a lot of sense; elders have experience with rare events that might prove crucial to the survival of the group if they were to recur, they may have better perspective of the rarity of other events, be able to spot patterns, etc. If we look at our history as a species, there have been a LOT more examples of what amount to geriocracies than societies run by the very young.

Really, examples of rulers who were extremely young almost always come from a system that is very rigid and legalistic in it's form succession, and in which other options were limited. Pretty much, the only way we have seen societies ruled by children is where an absolute monarch or emperor died and the only legally acceptable claimant to the throne was very young. It is entirely possible to have this happen in a modern society (think of North Korea and imagine if the supreme ruler were to die and leave a young son). There is a major caveat however! Just technically holding power is NOT the same as having legitimacy! Many, many monarchs and dictators across history have struggled endlessly to be really accepted by their people (who never really gave them legitimacy through voluntary means like an election). In the USA, we like to talk about a President having a "mandate", and that is very similar. It's not just a question of who is technically "in charge", but who LEADS and who do people feel represents them or *deserves* to lead. This is a VERY tricky question, and in almost all historical cases of child rulers, it is a question that was very problematic for the child ruler in question. This is why regents were customary in pretty much *every* society that had provision for child rulers.

So to answer the question as fairly as I can: to be a REAL ruler as you specify, I would say the youngest age would actually be upper teens, where the child no longer seems to be a child to most people, but can be perceived as an adult. Younger than that, and you are running into an endless problem of battling perceptions, questions of legitimacy and mandate, and trying to paddle upstream against human nature.

Or, just have a regent.

Comment: Excellent answer it reminded me immediately of http://bit.ly/2hFZ98V & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRrV1ff33iM

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your political system.

For a current age western style democracy it's unlikely to see a president under the 40's. Candidates are usually party leaders as well and climbing to that position requires knowing and getting enough allies/followers. That takes time.

For an XVII-XVIII century absolute king? As early as the custom allows. The king just needs to have a personality strong enough to not be manipulated by the former regent or ministers.
For example, Charles XII of Sweden was crowned at the age of 14. Well, *was crowned* is incorrect, he actually *crowned himself* and concentrated all power on himself.

Edit:

So your child is the inheritor of an modern autocracy under the disguise of a democracy. That makes him closer to a king than a democracy president, except without the reverence and tradition coming along with a crown and a much more conditional (aka weaker) power base. 
Your child will need to fill his father's shoes very quickly and maybe do a couple shows of force, since his supporters had more interest than actual loyalty and that kind of support fades fast.

For a number, I'd say 16 at least, earlier than that and he'd be too easily ignored.

Answer (score 3):

## Some examples of young men who created their own power

There is a different from inheriting a throne and power at a young age (Louis XIV, for example) and creating your own power. Here are some young men who created a name for themselves at a young age.

- Alexander became king of a middling country at 20, decided he was part deity, and immediately started a war with every other country on Earth. Somehow this wasn't a disaster, and now he's called 'the Great' and has a really big city named after him.
- Octavian Caesar was thrust into the limelight at age 19 when his uncle Julius was stabbed to death. He immediately allied with his uncle's senior sub-ordinate and made a name for himself destroying his uncle's murderers. He spend the next 13 years intriguing himself into power, until he had indisputed *imperium*, and renamed himself Augustus. Now he has a month named after him.

## Counterpoint

Those guys above might have started at 19, but here is a girl who finished there. God told Joan of Arc to save France when she was 13. She asked a local garrison commander for an escort to the Dauphin, so she could help him save France. He laughed at her. Two of his soldiers believed her, and she finally convinced him that she had heard the Word of God.

The Dauphin worried that she was a witch. He commissioned an inquiry into her life (of all male, priests), which determined that she was a true and pure Christian. The Dauphin sent her to Orleans to relieve the 5-month seige. While the Duc d'Orleans excluded her from his war councils, she lead from the front lines holding a banner. Following her, troops from Armagnac recaptured two outlying posts from the besiegers immediately after she arrived. Joan was wounded in the neck by an arrow, and the English retreated the next day.

Now with her momentum unstoppable, Joan decided to retakes some bridges. She didn't have an army, but Duc d'Alencon did, and followed her advice in strategy. They retook key bridges and three towns, defeated the English in the field for the first time in 100 years.

In any case, she was soon captured and burnt at the stake as a witch. So you have three options here: she was a witch, she was an agent of God, or she was a 14-year old political prodigy.

Comment: This actually supports my answer. I came to the conclusion that upper teens were the age floor for a real ruler.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to depend a LOT on the culture. Today, now? Well, you could look at [Jean-Claude Duvalier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Claude_Duvalier), who became President of Haiti when he was 19; he did not do a good job, and anyone in the same position as your youngster is going to invite comparison with him.

In another world, another time...well, you have control of the culture, so you can set things up almost any way you want. For example, [Padme Amidala of Naboo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5844/how-did-a-14-year-old-get-elected-queen) in the Star Wars universe was elected Queen at the age of 14; she's probably a good model for your young ruler as well, since she was picked out as a gifted child and trained as a legislator from the age of eight.

Really, since we're worldbuilding, you have all the control you want over your world to set whatever age you want. In a sci-fi setting, you could even give the child genetic advantages or cybernetic implants to bump up their ability.